# Scraping failing to retrieve the right number of nodes using htmlParse() getnodeset() and html_nodes()

Tags: r, xml-parsing, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I was trying to scrape the Zoopla website in order to get each one of the properties advertised converted into a single R dataFrame. For that I am using the XML, rvest and RCurl packages.

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
```

I've loaded a link that takes all the properties around London using getURL, the number of properties displayed can be controlled by a size parameter in the end of the url.

```
zoopla_web  = getURL("http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/w1/west-end-mayfair-soho-marylebone-south/?q=w1&category=residential&radius=0&include_retirement_homes=true&include_shared_ownership=true&new_homes=include&polyenc=sk~zHney%40ni%40d%7Db%40dhN%7CvXjjo%40hoFjy%5En_d%40bbL%7BtAxaIczRawHwgeAgaHo%7CSejAmaqA_kEsmTcvHogJmkKc~Eukd%40uqGw~F%3FwhM~zKosF~oUct%40f~vA&search_source=refine&page_size=300&pn=1&view_type=list")
```

The **size** is controlled by this chunk at the end of the url

```
&page_size=300&pn=1&view_type=list
```

Initially I´ve set the size to 50 for trying to get each one of the properties as a node using XPath, for that I´ve parsed the web using htmlParse() (I've also tried html() with the same result) and converted it to nodes using getNodeSet()

```
dc          = htmlParse(zoopla_web)
nodeGeneral = getNodeSet(dc,'//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "listing-results-right", " " ))]')
```

**QUESTION:** When I set the size of the url to be 50 it worked perfectly and nodeGeneral was a list of 50 nodes, the same happened for 100, 120, but above 123 (for example 300) I am only getting 123 nodes.

I believe it is not a failure of the getURL since the size of the file grows bigger when size is set from 123 to 200 and gets higher and higher when increased. My guess is there is something wrong with getNodeSet() or htmlParse() functions. Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Using only the rvest package can be done and the problem remains the same, 123 nodes when 150 are expected

```
dc          = html("http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/w1/west-end-mayfair-soho-marylebone-south/?q=w1&category=residential&radius=0&include_retirement_homes=true&include_shared_ownership=true&new_homes=include&polyenc=sk~zHney%40ni%40d%7Db%40dhN%7CvXjjo%40hoFjy%5En_d%40bbL%7BtAxaIczRawHwgeAgaHo%7CSejAmaqA_kEsmTcvHogJmkKc~Eukd%40uqGw~F%3FwhM~zKosF~oUct%40f~vA&search_source=refine&page_size=150&pn=1&view_type=list")
nodeGeneral = html_nodes(dc,xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "listing-results-right", " " ))]')
```

Comment: You are using a weird combination of packages. I'd recommend you actually use rvest instead of XML

Comment: Hi hadley, I actually started using rvest only, but since the CSS selectors were not working properly I had to use xpath. Now I´ve realized that html_nodes() also support Xpath and I tried it again using only rvest package. But the same problem is happening, only 123 nodes when 150 were expected:

Comment: You're in violation of _"You agree not to use any automated software to view the Services without consent and to only access our Services manually."_ in their [ToS](http://www.zoopla.co.uk/terms/).

Comment: Thanks hrbmstr, I didn't realize about that, obviously I am doing this only for learning purposes, to try the capabilities of the previously mentioned packages and to try to discover why nor rvest, nor XML are able to get more than 123 nodes.